# Angular - Phonegap - "min-height: 100%" not working at all

Tags: html, css, angularjs, cordova

I have this html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/platform.css" />
        <title>1001Carros</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
                angular.bootstrap(document, ['Application']);
            }, false);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-view></body>
</html>
```

Using this stylesheet:

```
/* Low density (120), mdpi */
@import url('main-android-ldpi.css') screen and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 0.9999999);
@import url('main-android-ldpi-portrait.css') screen and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 0.9999999) and (orientation: portrait);
@import url('main-android-ldpi-landscape.css') screen and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 0.9999999) and (orientation: landscape);
/* Medium density (160), mdpi */
@import url('main-android-mdpi.css') screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1);
@import url('main-android-mdpi-portrait.css') screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.4999999) and (orientation: portrait);
@import url('main-android-mdpi-landscape.css') screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.4999999) and (orientation: landscape);
/* High density (240), hdpi */
@import url('main-android-hdpi.css') screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5);
@import url('main-android-hdpi-portrait.css') screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.9999999) and (orientation: portrait);
@import url('main-android-hdpi-landspace.css') screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.9999999) and (orientation: landscape);
/* Extra high density (320), xhdpi */
@import url('main-android-xhdpi.css') screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2);
@import url('main-android-xhdpi-portrait.css') screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait);
@import url('main-android-xhdpi-landscape.css') screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape);

 /****************************************************************************************************************
 * En realidad estos estilos que estan aca valen tambien para iPhone - tengo que moverlos a algun css en comun. *
 ****************************************************************************************************************/
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: green;
}

/*...*/

#block-content {
    background-color: #0058a9;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#block-footer {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: #bbbbbb;
}

#block-content-ender {
    clear: both;
}

/*...*/
```

In those `@import`ed files, no more specs for `#block-footer` or `#block-content`, `html`, `body`, or `#block-content-ender` are defined.

Finally, the ng-view (which is in the `body` tag) directive correctly puts the following content inside via `ngRoute`:

```
<div id="block-logo">
    <button id="btn-go-main" class="btn-blue-gradient"></button>
</div>
<div id="block-search">
    <div id="search-box">
        <div id="search-box-btn" ng-click="doSearch()"></div>
        <input type="text" id="search-box-text" ng-model="searchText" placeholder="Buscar Ej. Rojo, Chevrolet, Vitara" />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="block-content">
    <div id="floating-guys">
        <div id="tall-guy"></div>
        <div id="short-guy"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="main-menu">
        <ul id="options" class="menu">
            <li ng-repeat="button in buttons"
                ng-attr-id="button.id"
                ng-class="{'menu-row': true, 'section': button.section, 'clickable': !button.section}"
                ng-style="button.styles"
                ng-click="button.click()">
                {{ button.text }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="block-content-ender"></div>
</div>
<div id="block-footer">
    Lugar para el banner de pie
</div>
```

Upon reading the styles, one can notice that `html` and `body` have a min-height of 100%. For debug purposes, they have a `green` background color.

One can also notice that `#block-logo`, `#block-search`, `#block-content` and `#block-footer` do not belong to any tag in the file, and are included inside `ng-view`-holder (i.e. the `body` tag).

One can also notice that `#block-content` is defined like `html` and `body`:

```
#block-content {
    background-color: #0058a9;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Except because it has a blue-like background color.

What I expected is that `#block-content` should have, as minimal height, the height of the body (i.e. since the background of `#block-content` is blue-like, I expected to see a remanent, empty, blue-like section at the bottom).

Unfortunately, the `min-height` style in `#block-content` is not working: **it has not effect at all** - It is the same if I remove it (i.e. since the background of the body is green, I actually saw a remanent green section at the bottom).

Except for that, the content is working as I expected - have no problems with ngRoute at all.

**My question is**: why? What I intend is to have such block having the height of the body, at least.

**I also tried** having a div inside the body and holding the ng-view directive:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <!-- -same head -->
    <body>
        <div id="content" ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Having its own style:

```
/* this style still existed */
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: green;
}

#content { min-height: 100%; background-color: red; }
```

But neither had efect at all (i.e. the background of `#content` is red -> I expected a remaining red section; however I saw a remaining green section -> the `body` behind).

**Again**: How can I force such 100%-tall divs?

**Note**: This is **not** about the background color. I actually need to fix the `#block-footer` to the bottom, being the bottom at -at least- 100% of the device height (it will hold a footer-banner).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding your height issue -- you need to explicitly set the `html` tag to 100% height. A child element can only use reference height properties of a parent that has an explicitly set height. After `html` has an explicit height set, you can set the `body` to `min-height 100%`.

Regarding your footer, to stick a footer to the bottom of the visual viewport:

```
footer {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It could help BUT if, by some reason, the actual contents of the site reaches 100% or more, a fixed footer would overlap that content. Also, if I need my `#block-content` to have a custom background, I will not see it spanned to the bottom if the page content height is below 100%

Comment: html and body already have a minimal height of 100%. I tried making them have height:100% instead of min-height:100%, and the effect was the same.

Comment: yeah! it worked by using height instead of min-height! had cache issues (or perhaps the IDE did not save it)